# How to render page information in Angular without prerender.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat, prerender

I have a site in AngularJs and I cannot make prerender.io work.

I have my site in EC2 in a Tomcat server. The server has two apps (folders) one called ui with the angularjs project and other call api with a Java restfull project which provide webservices to the angularjs project.

Tomcat is configured to open ui folder as root, so the first thing that is executed is the index file in ui folder.

I tried with the Apache middleware for prerender.io but it doesn't work. I guess it is because I'm using Tomcat and not apache.

So is there any other solution/library to have facebook, google, bing, etc search engines to render correctly mi site? So far it appears as {{title}} and {{description}} as the site is updating this dinamically. It's a big issue from javascript frameworks, that it should have a natural solution, instead of adding another middleware that is not free (free until a limited amount of pages)